# Laser beam divergence

Tags: optics, laser

How can I calculate the divergence of a laser beam by diffraction? I want to find the following relation,

$$
\Delta\Omega = \frac{\lambda^2}{A},
$$

where $\lambda$ is the wavelength and $A$ is the area.
[image: laser in cavity]

this is the laser in a cavity.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You want a derivation of the diffraction equation? Or do you want to see how this equation is applied in a special case?

Comment: really i wanna find angular laser beam divergence by diffraction relations. ΔΩ=λ^2/A = (∆θ)^2

Comment: Presumably $\Omega$ is the solid angle, in which case your expression is essentially the square of the [expression for the width of an Airy disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk#Size).

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you are asking about laser beams in the fundamental, diffraction limited Gaussian mode.  The standard expression for the divergence angle of a Gaussian beam in the far field is (see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Beam_divergence) on Gaussian beams) 
$$
\theta=\frac{\lambda}{\pi\omega_0}
$$
where $\omega_0$ is the so-called waist size of the Gaussian beam.  From here you can calculate the solid angle subtended by the beam which is given, in the small $\theta$ limit, as
$$
\Theta\simeq\pi\theta^2=\frac{\lambda^2}{\pi\omega_0^2}=\frac{\lambda^2}{A},
$$
where $A$ is the area of the beam's waist.

If you are looking for a derivatation which starts at a more fundamental level than that, then you should pick up any textbook on lasers.  Any textbook you can find will cover the derivation of the Gaussian modes of a laser beam from the wave/Helmholtz equation.  You can also look at section 2.1 of [my thesis](http://www.chrislmueller.com/documents/Chris_Mueller_Thesis.pdf) where I sketch out the derivation from the Helmholtz equation although I stop slightly short of deriving the divergence angle.